# Read notification in Kinto

Tags: python, pyramid, kinto

In Kinto I would like to get read notifications. I have following settings:

```
kinto.event_listeners = testev
kinto.event_listeners.testev.actions = read
kinto.event_listeners.testev.use = fnc_testev
```

The notification is triggered, but only once. To receive it again, I have to UPDATE the record and after that, the first GET triggers notification again. Additional identical GET requests receive correct HTTP response, but no notification to fnc_testev. Is that by design, or am I missing something?

In fact, I would like to get read notification after the transaction commit (AfterResourceRead). Is that available in Kinto?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP header Cache-Control: no-store does not help. Kinto internally detects Not Modified condition, but returns cached response (possibly modified in read notification, so this is OK for me). To trigger read notification again, use `?_since=timestamp` in query string or `If-None-Match` HTTP header.

To get after read notification, I used Kinto plugin and `config_add_subscriber` function.